# APFS doesn’t fully support AFP

Tags: high-sierra, afp, apfs

After I upgraded to High Sierra's APFS, `afp://ipadress` no long show me files on the remote computer’s APFS drive (only spinning drive shows up, and if the remote computer doesn’t have a spinning drive I cannot visit the computer). But `afp://computername` still works.

Comment: What's your question here? Apple APFS FAQ: [Can I reshare APFS-formatted volumes using a network file-sharing protocol?](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/APFS_Guide/FAQ/FAQ.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016999-CH6-DontLinkElementID_1) 1. Yes, you can share APFS-formatted volumes using the SMB or NFS network file-sharing protocol. 2. You cannot share APFS-formatted volumes using AFP. The AFP protocol is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't. Use SMB instead.